# Angular 5 not re-rendering img tag after [src] attribute changed

Tags: javascript, html, angular, image, gif

I'm building a reddit client app with Angular 5 which has the following snippet of code

```
  <div class="post-image" *ngIf="!post.media && !post.is_self">
    <img class="image" [src]="postImage()">
  </div>
```

This is the function that returns the image ur:

```
  postImage(): string {
    return this.post.preview.images[0].variants.gif
      ? this.post.preview.images[0].variants.gif.source.url
      : this.post.preview.images[0].source.url;
  }
```

As you can see, the `img` tag can either receive an url to a gif or a regular image file. The `this.post` variable is an Input variable that changes whenever the user selects a new post.

Now, the problem is, whenever I switch between two posts that display a regular image file, the image tag will re-render just fine, but when I switch between two posts that will display a `.gif` file, the image tag will simply not re-render, it will keep displaying the previous `.gif`.

Now, I've checked the rendered code already to see if the image `src` value was actually changing in this scenario, and the image `src` value does change, but the `.gif` will not re-render. The title and everything else in the component that renders the post will update, except the image tag. I have no idea what could be causing that problem.

EDIT: I think it might be helpful to add than I am running this app inside Electron.js, maybe that has something to do with the problem.

Comment: I guess rerender depends on related attributes, so I need you try something like `this.imgsrc = this.postImage()` and `<img class="image" [src]="imgsrc">`

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be cache browser
You can do look like this

```
 postImage(): string {
    return this.post.preview.images[0].variants.gif
      ? this.post.preview.images[0].variants.gif.source.url + '&date=' + new Date().getTime();
      : this.post.preview.images[0].source.url + '&date=' + new Date().getTime();
  }
```

Comment: I think you should user '?date=' + new Date().getTime();
instead '&date=' + new Date().getTime();